# Draw circle and drag touch around SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d

I am making a Sprite Kit game where the player (basically a stickman) has a running animation and a parallax scrolling background.

Now I have enemies that come near my player. To destroy these enemies sometimes I have to touch the enemies node to launch a rocket or attack them with an attack button or just jump over them.

Everything is working fine, but I want to add some extra moves to destroy them. I want some enemies that you can just destroy if you have drawn a whole circle around them. So imagine they come and you make a circle and then my player launch a laser or something. The problem is I have no idea where to start.

I haven't found anything on the internet. If it's too complicated or almost impossible how about touching my player node and dragging to the enemy?

EDIT: I think I have to create a custom GestureRecognizer that recognizes if a circle is drawn around a sprite and then runs the code. I don't know how this works ?

Comment: add code snippet/screen shots of whatever you have tried now.

Comment: i would like to but i don't have any code yet, cause i don't have a clue where to start. if you need more information just let me know. do someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's too complex. Not just from a coding point of view, but also from that of the player's experience.

Anything that requires complex gestures over a large amount of glass is annoying for the player because they're never going to have the same experience. Their finger's moisture and oil content always changes, as does the ambient temperature and cleanliness of their screen.

So big gestures required to be performed quickly (a gaming input like this) will sometimes be fun and smooth, and other times degrade as an experience based on the nature of the above properties.

Best to avoid them for a game's best possible experience.

If you must do it, there's two ways to research how.

1. Seek out "custom gesture" creation and utilisation through documentation and google, etc.
2. Think about using some kind of array to store all the points where the player's finger moves through during that circle gesture and attempt to discern if an enemy is within that space and then act accordingly.

--- probably other ways, too. But these jump to mind.